# Flutter when clicked button will POST data to API but fail

Tags: flutter, api, post

I create food order app with flutter, but i found some error on my code when i try to create some button which works for POST data to API. I hope you guys can help me, your help is very useful for me, thank you

this is a response from API,
This is an example of the data that can be sent

```
{
"nominal_diskon": "50000",
"nominal_pesanan": "100000",
"items": [
    { "id": 1, "harga": 10000, "catatan": "Tes" },
    { "id": 2, "harga": 10000, "catatan": "Tes" },
    { "id": 3, "harga": 10000, "catatan": "Tes" }
]}
```

this is a transaction_service.dart

```
    class TransactionService {
      String baseUrl = 'https://tes-mobile.landa.id/api';
    
      Future<bool> checkout(
          double diskon, double totalprice, List<MenuModel> menus) async {
        var url = '$baseUrl/order';
        var body = jsonEncode(
          {
            'nominal_diskon': diskon,
            'nominal_pesanan': totalprice,
            'items': menus
                .map(
                  (menu) =>
                      {'id': menu.id, 'harga': menu.harga, 'catatan': menu.catatan},
                )
                .toList(),
          },
        );
    
        var response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(url),
          body: body,
        );
    
        print(response.body);
    
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return true;
        } else {
          throw Exception('Gagal Melakukan Checkout!');
        }
      }

}
```

this is a transaction_provider.dart

```
class TransactionProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  Future<bool> checkout(
      double diskon, double totalprice, List<MenuModel> menus) async {
    try {
      if (await TransactionService().checkout(diskon, totalprice, menus)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

this is a home_page.dart which runs the button

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String voucherCode = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MenuProvider menuProvider = Provider.of<MenuProvider>(context);
    VoucherProvider voucherProvider = Provider.of<VoucherProvider>(context);
    TransactionProvider transactionProvider =
        Provider.of<TransactionProvider>(context);
    double hargaAkhir =
        menuProvider.totalPrice() - voucherProvider.diskonHarga();
    handleCheckout() async {
      if (await transactionProvider.checkout(
        10000,
        100000,
        menuProvider.menus,
      )) {
        
        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context, '/order-page', (route) => false);
      }
    }

    Widget content() {
      return ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 25,
        ),
        children: menuProvider.menus
            .map(
              (menu) => MenuCard(menu),
            )
            .toList(),
      );
    }

    Widget customBottomNav() {
      ...
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: handleCheckout,
                      child: Text('Pesan Sekarang',
                          style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
                              fontWeight: bold, fontSize: 14)),
                      color: menuProvider.totalItems() >= 1
                          ? kPrimaryColor
                          : kDarkGreyColor,
                      textColor: kWhiteColor,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        side: BorderSide(
                          color: menuProvider.totalItems() >= 1
                              ? Color(0xFF00717F)
                              : kDarkGreyColor,
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kWhiteColor,
      body: content(),
      bottomNavigationBar: customBottomNav(),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the error message

Comment: no error, but on debug like this 
I/flutter (25763): {"status_code":400,"message":"Order gagal dibuat"}

Comment: It means your api is able to send the response. Check if you are calling proper route (could be typo) or auth issue